# Raspberry Pi running Raspian in Telnet

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi3, telnet, beep

I have a few Raspberry Pi devices (*b3+*) running a telnet session to our server at work.  Warehouse employees scan bar codes to move product through the warehouse.  These Raspberry Pi devices are running Raspbian and have replaced handheld scanners (*since the warehouse staff kept breaking them*).  These Pi devices boot up into the terminal and establish a telnet connection with the server.

The handheld scanners that were replaced by these Pi devices, provided an audio warning tone if something didn't scan correctly (*we're assuming it was an ascii generation*), which allowed users to be notified of the error.  After bashing my head against the wall - and pretty much anything else I can find - I'm hoping someone here can help me out.

I'm looking for a way for the Pi to generate a warning sound while in the telnet session...using ascii 7 (*I'm not sure if any text is returned when the error is received or not*).  The sound will need to be transmitted from the Pi to the display speakers via an HDMI connection.  Any suggestions?

NOTE: We can get wav files to play off the Pi using the CLI...we just can't quite get ascii 7 to return a warning/beep.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/audio-config.md In other words, if there's no audio going to HDMI now, and explicitly configuring it for HDMI doesn't fix it, you'll have to do something else. It could be a terminal setting as well.

Comment: Audio does go through the HDMI currently, we can successfully play the default wav files on the Pi...we cannot, however, get a warning/beep to occur with ascii 7.

Comment: Then it's either a terminal setting, or the terminal/telnet program is eating ^Gs.